# appcompat-v7: Custom view not properly aligned in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat

I am trying to use Appcompat Toolbar based actionBar

Here is my toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am including this in my activity.xml file.
And then in my Activity's OnCreate method,  I am setting a custom PagerStrip into ActionBar

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.pager_strip);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    tabs =  (PagerSlidingTabStrip) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tabs_strip);
    tabs.setViewPager(mPager);
```

There is some padding below my PagerStrip in ActionBar. I want to remove this padding.
here is a picture showing the issue. 
[image]

This was working fine with ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem: I have migrated to the Toolbar pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <my.custom.widget.class
            android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </my.custom.widget.class>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

but the AppCompat gave me a strange padding around my custom view:
[image]

#### My fix:

Add `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` and `app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"` to the Toolbar attributes; and `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` to the custom widget attributes.

Result:
[image]

Not sure that the solution follows the Material design guidelines, but hope it will help to someone.

Comment: I am trying to use toolbar instead of actionbar however getting `InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment' I am using navigationdrwaer also. Is there a way to use toolbar with navigationdrawer?

Comment: I tried to add TabStrip in same way as you through xml. But I had width set as "wrap_content". But when app loaded, Action bar didn't show my tabStrip. Could you verify if its works for you even with wrap_content ?

Comment: worked for me ! Add app:contentInsetStart="0dp" and app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" to the Toolbar attributes

Comment: @AhmedNawaz do you want the tabs under the toolbar?

Answer (score -2):

Toolbar is widget replacement for Actionbar in some cases.
If you want to use Toolbar then you can try:

```
Toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewbyId(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionbar(toolbar);
```

I used Toolbar in DrawerLayout. My navigation drawer can always Top Toolbar.

P/S: use toolbar in ActionBarActivity

Comment: Hi. Can you share complete code of your class? I am stucked in this. I am using navigation Drawer